# Angular: Evaluating a function on controller scope then passing it to a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to evaluated a function on the parent controller then send it into a directive.  I need the values to be watched by the digest loop and updated when a user updates them.

I've worked through some original issues, but am having trouble with getting the bindings to update.

I have a **Controller** with an object and a function that checks if an object has values, it returns true or false:

```
   this.foo = {
    obj1: {
        name: '',
        time: 'time2'
    },
    obj2: {
        name: 'name2',
        time: 'time2'
    }
};


this.isPaneComplete = function(tab) {
    var complete = true;
    var tab2 = tab.tab;
    for (var prop in tab2) {
        if (tab2.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            complete = !!tab2[prop] && complete;
        }
    }
    return complete;
};
```

I have a directive called MyPane with this scope :

```
  scope: {
      completed : '&myPaneComplete'
    },
```

This is my template:

```
<my-pane my-pane-complete="gigEditCtrl.isPaneComplete({tab : gigEditCtrl.foo.obj1})">
<input type="text" placeholder="2014-12-31" ng-model="gigEditCtrl.foo.obj1.name">
<input type="text" placeholder="2014-12-31" ng-model="gigEditCtrl.foo.obj1.time">
```

When running the following console.log I get TRUE or FAlSE in my Directive

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
          console.log(scope.completed());
        },
```

This all works great.  However, when I update the values in the input boxes the controller function isn't run again and the console.log isn't fired. Thoughts?

Comment: what you get when you run `console.log(scope.completed)` is the definition of wrapper that angular build for the parent function. if you run `console.log(scope.completed())` angular will call `isPaneComplete()` in your controller

Comment: Ya i'm getting undefined.  And when I do a console.log of tab in the ctlr's function it doesn't fire.  Seems like my syntax is wrong and it never actually runs the function...

Comment: You need to show us more code, if you can setup a plunker that would be great

Comment: I updated the code above, got the value passed into the directive, can't get it to update when I change a value though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for your issue is to use `$watch` in your directive and it will look something like this

```
testApp.directive('myDir', function(){
   return{
                scope:{
                    test: '&'
                },
                link: function(scope, el, attrs){
                    scope.$watch(scope.test, function(newValue){
                        console.log('from dir name =  '+ newValue);
                    });
                }
            };
 });
```

basically you will you will use `$watch` to watch changes in the return value of your function.

I've setup a working demo for you here http://plnkr.co/edit/Gk2tILTql8NW1QkvVRRk?p=preview

Comment: Works perfectly, I knew I had to watch something but I thought it was the object in the controller!

Comment: @ndynan you could do that but then you have to call the function manually, but with the above approach angular will call it automatically for you